# query to match first higher match and ignore subsequent higher values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

Contents of table1 :

```
name  abase1        dz      pline    
 acc       1         1      123.45  
 acc       2         1      128.20
 acc       3         2      130.20
 acc       4         2      135.20
```

table2

```
 name          bbase1           chigh
   acc           1              128.20
   acc           2              130.25
   acc           3              145.20 
   acc           4              128.05
   acc           5              148.20   
   acc           6              149.50 
   acc           7              148.70
```

I want to join the above two table  with a condition that  bbase is > abase and first chigh > pline and ignore subsequent greater chigh for a particular abase1  and want the following result

```
  name      abase1           pline      bbase1      chigh
   acc           1            123.45       3        145.20
   acc           2            128.20       3        145.20  
   acc           3            130.20       5        148.20 
   acc           4            135.20       6        149.50
```

Can you help me out either in query or vba, since my query is not working properly

```
select a.acc,a.abase1,a.pline,b.bbase1,b.chigh from table1 as a  inner join table2 as b on a.name=b.name and a.abase1<b.bbase1 and a.pline <b.chigh
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.acc,a.abase1,a.pline,b.bbase1,b.chigh 
from table1 as a  
inner join table2 as b 
    on a.name=b.name and a.abase1<b.bbase1 and a.pline <b.chigh
left join table2 as c
    on c.name = a.name and a.abase1 < c.bbase1 and a.pline < c.chigh and b.bbase1 > c.bbase1 and b.chigh > c.chigh
where c.bbase1 is null
```

Comment: Hi thomas, thansks for your reply,   When I am using the query suggested i get error "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.   If I try two seperate queries then, I do not get the desired result for eg: abase4 I want chigh is 149.50,but query result is 148.20.  Actually, I want the maximum chigh before chigh is going down and subsequent chigh after down will be ignored